# if statement not working when checking for display:none

Tags: jquery

```
$("table").everyTime(5000, function(){  

if(($("#morning").css("display")) != "none"){
    $("#morning").hide();
    $("#afternoon").show();
}else{
$("#morning").show();
    $("#afternoon").hide();
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sample.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

}, 0);

});
```

my table morning starts as being visible, so when my if statement runs every 5 seconds it should hide it then make the next table visible. When morning is not visible i want it to be set as visible.

For some reason, what looks to be a simple if statement, is not working. If I get rid of the else it will hide morning and show afternoon. But, when the else is added, nothing really happens.

Comment: Have you check what value `$("#morning").css("display")` **does have** if its not "none"?

Comment: Are you sure your #morning element isn't being hidden by a parent with display:none?

Comment: well what exactly is visible and display? if i have no attribute for morning, what is added when i use hide() or show()?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.is(':visible')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead. It may namely not necessarily have exactly that attribute.

```
if ($("#morning").is(":visible")) {
    $("#morning").hide();
    $("#afternoon").show();
} else {
    $("#morning").show();
    $("#afternoon").hide();
}
```

Alternatively, if the one is always hidden when the other is visible, you can also use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
$("#morning").toggle();
$("#afternoon").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").everyTime(5000, function(){  

  if($("#morning").is(':visible')){
    $("#morning").hide();
    $("#afternoon").show();
  } else {
    $("#morning").show();
    $("#afternoon").hide();
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sample.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });

}, 0);
```

Comment: You're doing the opposite of what the OP wants. This will never enter one of the blocks.

Comment: visible doesnt work for me... if i take out the else it works. There must be something wrong with the else

Comment: i put an alert in the else when it's not visible and it is running both parts of the if statement. It's not doing either/or. this doesnt make any sense.